# Stripe Webhooks - Diferentes códigos de respuestas

Tags: stripe, webhook

Estuve revisando en la documentación de Stripe, y nos sugiere que respondamos los más pronto posible con un código 200 "Debe ser antes de nosotros procesarlo en nuestra base de datos" https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#acknowledge-events-immediately.

**Tengo algunas dudas:**

¿Es estrictamente requerido enviar siempre a Stripe el código de respuesta 200?

¿En que casos es necesario enviar a Stripe otro código de respuesta? Como estos: https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors

¿Que sucedería si después de enviar el código 200 a Stripe, el sistema por alguna razón falla al procesar en mi base de datos un evento, actualizar alguna factura, subscripción etc... Puedo responder a Stripe con una respuesta 402 para que me reenvíe ese mismo evento, sería una buena práctica?

¿Como puedo pedirle a Stripe que envíe nuevamente un mismo evento?

¿Después de enviar a Stripe un código de respuesta 200, puede Stripe reintentar enviar un mismo evento?

Agradezco su aporte! Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Es estrictamente requerido enviar siempre a Stripe el código de respuesta 200?

No es requerido un 200, puedes responder con cualquier código 200-299 (2xx) para indicar que procesaste el evento exitosamente. Si no estás preparado para procesar el evento, puedes responder 3xx, 4xx, 5xx como estimes conveniente (e.g. 402), y Stripe reenviará el evento más tarde.

Lo importante que indica la documentación, es que tu webhook endpoint sea "rápido", y no tenga tiempos de respuesta largos, ya que si la respuesta toma mucho tiempo, Stripe considera ese webhook como fallido y lo reintentará nuevamente.

> ¿Que sucedería si después de enviar el código 200 a Stripe, el sistema por alguna razón falla al procesar en mi base de datos un evento, actualizar alguna factura, subscripción etc... Puedo responder a Stripe con una respuesta 402 para que me reenvíe ese mismo evento, sería una buena práctica?

Te recomiendo que diseñes tu sistema para que haga lo siguiente:

1. Construyes un endpoint para Stripe webhooks (e.g. /webhooks)
2. Al recibir un evento, lo pones en una cola (e.g. Redis) para procesarlo asíncronamente
3. Un proceso asíncrono consume eventos de la cola, y reintenta el procesamiento hasta que sea exitoso.

> ¿Como puedo pedirle a Stripe que envíe nuevamente un mismo evento? ¿Después de enviar a Stripe un código de respuesta 200, puede Stripe reintentar enviar un mismo evento?

Lo puedes hacer contestando un código HTTP 300 hacia arriba. Pero una vez que contestas con 2xx, Stripe ya no reintenta nuevamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias jlhonora, tengo una pregunta más ¿Que tiempo se toma Stripe en reenviar un evento?

Comment: Los eventos se reenvían con exponential backoff, partiendo con tres intentos dentro de la primera hora: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic